# how to be unblocked from First Application Android tutorial on layout constraint part

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui and am already finding there to be a misalignment between the description and my experience.  I'm told to add a plaintext element and should see this 
[image]

when I'm actually seeing this:

[image]

This has been super painful since I tried to coax the design view to show the `editText` bit to no avail and am forced to add a constraint that aligns the button label to the top of the edit text field instead of where the text would presumably sit as shown.

EDIT: I pasted the wrong picture in the initial post which didn't include a button and just corrected it.

EDIT2: The issue I was initially having was with Intellij IDEA, so I installed Android Studio to see if that would fix it but it appears to have made things worse as shown below, I'm not even able to see the text baseline for the button:

[image]

Comment: can you add your `.xml` file and clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AramSheroyan I'm trying to simply follow the tutorial. I don't know what I'm trying to achieve and the tutorial is failing to give me the early wins to get me going.

Comment: On simple UIs I recommend using LinearLayout. It's simpler and is rendered faster (https://android.jlelse.eu/constraint-layout-performance-870e5f238100).

Comment: @m0skit0 While I think linear can be more performant in certain situations, constraint layout is industry standard now for complex layouts. These tests are not capturing the whole picture.

Comment: For instance, if you have a layout with many linear layouts and nested layouts vs the flatter constraint layout, layout performance will remain constant with constraint, while the linear layout will decrease the performance with each nested layout.

Comment: @m0skit0 I would recommend you read the comments on that medium post to see what I mean.

Comment: @RichardDapice I think you missed the part on my comment when I say "simple UIs"

Comment: Looks like I did!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are on the right track.

Follow this step:

> To constrain the views in a horizontal alignment, create a constraint
>   between the text baselines. To do so, click the button and then click
>   Edit Baseline , which appears in the design editor directly below the
>   selected view. The baseline anchor appears inside the button. Click
>   and hold this anchor, and then drag it to the baseline anchor that
>   appears in the text box.

I would also recommend checking out the docs to gain a better understanding of how [constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) works. It is powerful and simple once you understand the basic concepts.

Here is the working code:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I realized that I added the wrong image where a button is expected to be shown.  I just updated it.

Comment: this issue might've been related to me using Intellij IDEA and not Android Studio so I installed studio to rule this out but am having another issue altogether.  I'd like to follow the instructions on the tutorial to the letter and not rely on outside information as I'm just starting and this tutorial is meant to be one for true beginners and was wondering if I can get information that aligns with this need.

Comment: I would be willing to look into that. Check out the above answer, if it meets the criteria of your question then mark it as the answer. Ask a follow-up question pertaining to your next issue.

Check out Udacities Android For Beginners Course.